# Javascript onClick given error

Tags: javascript

Javascript onClick not working.
This is what I have

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Vendors/Vendor1/ViewVendorProfile?id=" + 
         @ViewBag.VendorID)" 
   id="_@(ViewBag.VendorID)" 
   onClick="javascript: vendorinfo();">View Prof</a>
```

I get a javascript error saying

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

Comment: Use the JS debugger to find the bug.

Comment: Where is your `vendorinfo()` function??

Comment: I have it in my javascript code

Comment: @NatePet Please post it here.

Comment: You're not nesting your strings properly in the href tag

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could post the actual HTML for the link here, instead of the code. That way we could help you identify the issue better. As it stands right now, we have no idea whether the href URL exists and contains errors...or whether the link never reaches the URL.

Comment: href content doesn't look good with all the "

Comment: @Original, the nesting is fine. Razor is smart enough to parse it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your quotes as such:

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/Vendors/Vendor1/ViewVendorProfile?id=" + @ViewBag.VendorID)' 
    id='_@(ViewBag.VendorID)' 
    onClick="javascript: vendorinfo();">View Prof</a>
```